# How do I make my database calls execute before the data is used?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to display a bunch of stats related to the user on a webpage. I am making database calls to firebase and then using the data gotten from those calls to display the stats, but for some reason the stats are displaying before the calls are finished

Code:

```
function addStats() {
    let userMatches, wins, losses, ties;
    get(ref(database, `users/${user.uid}/matches`)).then(m => {
        userMatches = Object.values(m.val())
        userMatches.forEach((v, i) => {
            get(ref(database, `matches/${v}`)).then(m => {
                userMatches[i] = m.val()
                console.log('a')
            })
        })
        addStat('matchesPlayed', userMatches.length)
        console.log(userMatches)
    }).then(() => {
        const categories = userMatches.map(v => v.category)
        console.log(userMatches, categories)
        addStat('favCategory', getMode(categories))
    }).then(async () => {
        await(get(ref(database, `users/${user.uid}/wins`)).then(v => {
            wins = v.exists() ? v.val() : 0
            console.log(wins)
        }))
        await(get(ref(database, `users/${user.uid}/losses`)).then(v => {
            losses = v.exists() ? v.val() : 0
            console.log(losses)
        }))
        await(get(ref(database, `users/${user.uid}/tied`)).then(v => {
            ties = v.exists() ? v.val() : 0
            console.log(ties)
        }))
        addStat('wlt', [wins, losses, ties].join('/'))
    })
}
```

(All other functions are defined and working, this is the main area of problem)
In this, the variable categories is getting defined before the forEach loop, so it is getting set to undefined whereas it should be set to some number
I tried making different things async but nothing worked.

Comment: `get` I presume is an asynchronous something that returns a Promise ... so, the `get`s running inside `userMatches.forEach` are not going to be "waited" for before the rest of the promise chain gets executed. your mixture of `.then` with `async/await` doesn't help readability either

Comment: so how do i make it wait for the forEach loop? right now i'm just trying to make this work i'll refactor the code once i get it working

Comment: use .map and Promise.all - or use a regular for loop with await (addStats function will need to be async in this case)

Comment: first thing you need to decide is if you are using `async/await` or `.then` - mixing them is never going to be nice code

Comment: I think for `.then` - https://pastebin.com/DXQmqYtd ... and for `async/await` - https://pastebin.com/fpWp24g2

Comment: Thanks a lot! I actually worked out a different approach where it would detect when the forEach loop ended and then return to another function, but your approach seems more readable and better.